# Autdesk forge tracking element, model derivatives API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

Is there any way to track an element after publishing (translate) the 3D model by its metadata using:
[<kbd>GET</kbd>
**{urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties**](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/)?
Long time ago I heard that will be possible in SVF2.
In my case we would like to know the like cycle of the that element (moved or parameters update...)
More less like in BIM360 compare models.

Comment: As replied in the other post, a new API of BIM360 is on the way that can index the data of elements in versions. It can also tell the difference of versions. Please watch our update on Forge website, AU classes etc. Thank you for patience.

Comment: (@XiaodongLiang: can you please hyperlink the answer or comment [referred above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68879537/autdesk-forge-tracking-element-model-derivatives-api#comment121857290_68879537)?)

Comment: The other post is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904431/autodesk-forge-tracking-element-by-its-iexternalid